# Auto save edit text value and radio button selection

Tags: android, save, lostfocus

I have group of radio buttons and each radio button have one edit text, I want to save edit text value or radio button value on focus exited, perform auto save when focus is off.
please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **@Tushar Patil** You can get your answer easily on demo tutorials...and this question may duplicate. so put your question after R&D. will help you....

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TextWatcher` to do something after `onTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged`.

This is an example:

```
            final EditText ed = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);

            ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    //Save Your Text With SharedPreference
                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("TEST", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed_sp = sp.edit();
                    ed_sp.putString("myText", ed.getText().toString());
                    ed_sp.commit();
                    ShowSavedText();

                }
                void ShowSavedText(){
                    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("TEST", 0);
                    String savedText = sp.getString("myText", "");
                    tv.setText(savedText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your method `ShowSavedText` belongs to the `TextWatcher`? I would put that method outside the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for your requirement.

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got the focus",        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " auto save Here",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}
   });

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**100% Working Solution!**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
EditText myedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
String getmyedittext = sp.getString("savedcontent","");
myedittext.setText(getmyedittext, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

myedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        String savedcontentstring = myedittext.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("savedcontent", savedcontentstring);
        editor.apply();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) { }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }
});
```

P.S. I made some changes to Amir's code to prevent the app from crashing. Also, I added a few extra lines to make sure that when the app is re-opened, the contents are still there.